# FullCalendar - change date event

Tags: fullcalendar

I am using FullCalendar 2.3.1 and I am trying to load a spinner overlay over fullcalendar once I click previous or next month.
I tried to use:

```
var box;
$("#calendar").fullCalendar({
    lang: locale.substring(0, 2),
    header: {
        left: 'today prev,next',
        center: 'title',
        right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
    },
    loading: function(isLoading) {
        if (isLoading) {

        } else {
        }
    },
    dayClick: function() {
        alert('a day has been clicked!');
    },
    events: function (start, end, timezone, callback) {
        $.ajax({
            url: "http://"+window.location.host+"/db.php",
            data: "action=load_allevents",
            dataType: 'json',
            cache:false,
            async:false,
            success: function (data) {
                var events = [];
                $.each(data, function (index) {
                    events.push({
                        "id"                : data[index].id,
                        "title"             : data[index].room + " (" + data[index].i + ")",
                        "description"       : data[index].room + " (" + data[index].i + ")",
                        "start"             : moment(data[index].startdate),
                        "end"               : moment(data[index].enddate),
                        "backgroundColor"   : data[index].color,
                        "textColor"         : "#000000"
                    });
                });
                callback(events);
                if (box)
                    box.remove();
                startRender = false;
            },
            error: function () { alert('Failed!'); }
        });
    },
    eventRender: function(event, element) {
        if (!startRender) {
            box = new ajaxLoader(".calendar");
            startRender = true;
        }
        element.qtip({ content: { text: $.ajax({url:"http://"+window.location.host+"/db.php?action=load_eventdetails&ID="+event.id, async:false}).responseText } });
    },
    eventMouseover: function(calEvent, jsEvent) { $(jsEvent.target).css('cursor','pointer'); },
    eventClick: function(calEvent, jsEvent, view) {
        alert(calEvent.id);
    }
});
```

since I thought first time I click on previous or next month it would anyway fire eventRender event so I thought to check if it was first call of eventRender to load the spinner but it loaded only when it was all done...what I have missed?

Thanks in advance! 
Cheers
Luigi

Answer (score 1):

[eventRender](http://fullcalendar.io/docs/event_rendering/eventRender/) are used to render something while an event renders.

**Eg:** If you want to add a custom image at the end of every event Title or change background color of the event, then you can do using this.

You have to use "[Loading](http://fullcalendar.io/docs/event_data/loading/)" so that it triggered when event fetching starts/stops.

Also you need to use "[lazyfetching](http://fullcalendar.io/docs/event_data/lazyFetching/)".

The lazyFetching will allow your calendar to fetch events every time when the view changes (eg: prev/next clicked) to load events in the view. So it will not fetch from cache.

Use [eventAfterRender](http://fullcalendar.io/docs/event_rendering/eventAfterRender/) to code the tool tip therefore it will triggered after an event render completed.

```
lazyFetching: false,
loading: function(isLoading) {
    if (isLoading) {
        if (!startRender) {
        box = new ajaxLoader(".calendar");
        startRender = true;
        }
    }
    },
    eventAfterRender: function (view) {
    if (!startRender) {
        box = new ajaxLoader(".calendar");
        startRender = true;
    }
     element.qtip({ content: { text: $.ajax({url:"http://"+window.location.host+"/db.php?action=load_eventdetails&ID="+event.id, async:false}).responseText } });           
    },
```

Comment: Hello Prasanth, I tried as you said but if I have some events that are put in the grid once I click previous or next month button first it fires those qtip calls (which are to show details in a tooltip) then goes fire loading... why?..